# Flutter, Transform.scale with Duration?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Hi I`m looking for an example Transform.scale with Duration(milliseconds: 300..)

can I see an example please?

I have searched there is not example

Comment: `AnimatedScale`

Comment: @pskink hi there is no way to use with Transform.scale then? I want to practice Transform styles

Comment: of course you can use `Transform.scale` inside `AnimatedBuilder` (and with help of `AnimationController`) for example

Comment: @pskink Could you please share the code??

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/tutorial#refactoring-with-animatedbuilder

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of animations in Flutter: Implicit and Explicit. In your case, you seem to want an implicit widget to animate the change in scale of something. Luckily, there's a pre-made widget for you, called `AnimatedScale`. If that suits your needs, you should prefer to use that widget. If it doesn't, for example, if you want to apply other fancier transformations, you can try to use `Transform` widget with `TweenAnimationBuilder` to stay within the "implicit animation". This way you can avoid dealing with `AnimationController`, and can make your code concise.

Full example, replace `main.dart` with the code below to run it. Clicking the button will toggle the Flutter Logo between 1.0x and 5.0x scale:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _big = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            AnimatedScale(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              scale: _big ? 5.0 : 1.0,
              child: FlutterLogo(),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('change size'),
              onPressed: () => setState(() => _big = !_big),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like that

```
class TransformWithDuration extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final void Function()? onTap;
  final void Function()? onLongTap;
  const TransformWithDuration({Key? key, required this.child, this.onTap, this.onLongTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TransformWithDurationState createState() => _TransformWithDurationState();
}

class _TransformWithDurationState extends State<TransformWithDuration>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  double squareScaleA = 1;
  late AnimationController _controllerA;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controllerA = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      lowerBound: 0.94,
      upperBound: 1.0,
      value: 1,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
    _controllerA.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        squareScaleA = _controllerA.value;
      });
    });

    _controllerA.drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onTap: () {
        _controllerA.reverse();
        if (widget.onTap != null) widget.onTap!();
      },
      onTapDown: (dp) {
        _controllerA.reverse();
      },
      onTapUp: (dp) {
        Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {
          _controllerA.fling();
        });
      },
      onTapCancel: () {
        _controllerA.fling();
      },
      onLongPress: () {
        if (widget.onLongTap != null) widget.onLongTap!();
      },
      child: Transform.scale(
        scale: squareScaleA,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerA.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```